# Como se puede saber, los elementos que tiene un vector A y que no lo tiene un vector B y viceversa

Tags: c#

Tengo dos vectores y quisiera imprimir los elementos que no tiene un **vector A** pero no los que se repiten en el **Vector B**.

Esto tengo hasta ahora

```
static void interseccion_A_entre_B(int[] vectora, int[] vectorb)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < vectora.Length; c++)
        {
            for(int c2 = 0; c2 < vectorb.Length; c2++)
            {
                if (vectora[c] != vectorb[c2])
                {
                    Console.Write(vectora[c]);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, muestranos lo que intentaste hasta ahora.

Comment: static void interseccion_A_entre_B(int[] vectora, int[] vectorb)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < vectora.Length; c++)
            {
                for(int c2 = 0; c2 < vectorb.Length; c2++)
                {
                    if (vectora[c] != vectorb[c2])
                    {
                        Console.Write(vectora[c]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Comment: Lo que quieres es una diferencia? por ejemplo en A esta {1,3,5,7,9} y en B {7,5,2,8,4,36} y quieres imprimir {2,8,4,36} es asi no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazlo más fácil, con Linq lo puedes conseguir en una línea con `Except`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] v1 = { 2, 3, 1, 3, 8, 9 };
            int[] v2 = { 4, 2, 1, 6 };
            var items = v1.Except(v2);

            foreach (int item in items)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0},", item));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

El resultado será 3, 8, 9 (elementos de v1 que no están en v2)

Más info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Añado más información con tu duda. `Except` devuelve un IEnumerable. Con un simple `ToArray()` ya tendrías un nuevo array con la diferencia:

```
int[] items = v1.Except(v2).ToArray();
```

Y si quieres alternar entre v1 y v2 pásalos como parámetros a tu función:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] v1 = { 2, 3, 1, 3, 8, 9 };
            int[] v2 = { 4, 2, 1, 6 };

            int[] items1 = interseccion_A_entre_B(v1, v2);
            int[] items2 = interseccion_A_entre_B(v2, v1);

            Console.WriteLine("Elementos en v1 que no están en v2");
            foreach (int item in items1)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0},", item));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Elementos en v2 que no están en v1");
            foreach (int item in items2)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0},", item));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int[] interseccion_A_entre_B(int[] vectora, int[] vectorb)
        {
            return vectora.Except(vectorb).ToArray();
        }
```

Resultado:

Elementos en v1 que no están en v2
3,8,9,
Elementos en v2 que no están en v1
4,6,

Si quieres profundizar más te recomiendo la documentación de msdn sobre operaciones con arrays:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Ahí podrás ver métodos para copiar (Copy, CopyTo) y otras muchas funcionalidades.

Y la de Linq:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Piensa que hay muchas formas ya implementadas que facilitan mucho el manejo de conjuntos de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero se puede almacenar ese resultado en un nuevo vector y lo mismo que se comparo con el v1 y v2 ahora el v2 con el v1 y me de como resultado otro vector y unir los dos vectores para imprimir un solo vector